# mod-mono not working on CentOS/Apache

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono

I just set up mod-mono on my CentOS box and configured Apache to serve .aspx pages, but it's throwing errors whenever a page is served. The error is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mod-mono-server2, Version=2.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'mod-mono-server2, Version=2.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.GetApplicationForPath (System.String vhost, Int32 port, System.String path, Boolean defaultToRoot) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:GetApplicationForPath (string,int,string,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.GetOrCreateApplication (System.String vhost, Int32 port, System.String filepath, System.String virt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My mono prefix is `/opt/mono`. If I manually run `/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server2` it throws the same error (how can it not find itself?). Any idea on how to resolve this? It should be noted that I have a parallel mono installation in `/usr/local`, but `/opt/mono` comes first in `PATH`.

EDIT: I ran `/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server2` with verbose logging and I can see AOT attempting to load libraries and failing. Here is a paste of the log: http://hastebin.com/cijubibefe.log

Many of these libraries do not have shared object files with them. For example, `/opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll` exists (along with `System.dll.mdb`) but `/opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so` does not exist.

### EDIT2: Solved

I just figured it out. Somehow when I was building Mono, XSP, and mod-mono, my prefix didn't get obeyed for part of the build sequence and the launch scripts for executables such as `mod-mono-server2` were running with `/usr/local/bin/mono` instead of `/opt/mono/bin/mono`, which obviously didn't have mod-mono-server2 in GAC. Editing all the launch scripts to use `/opt/mono/bin/mono` fixed the issue.